# Completely delete a Ubuntu based docker container along with underlying layers of MySQL and JDK

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-layer

I have created custom docker image using Ubuntu 16.04 xenial as base image, and installed JDK-1.8 and MY-SQL layer on it. Following is sample snap-shot of my Dockerfile to create image.

```
# Use 0.9.19 as this is the last tag that uses Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.19

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# Maintained by Abhi
MAINTAINER Abhishek <abhi@gmail.com>

# Set the locale. Default locale causes some Perl regexes to fail.
# http://jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales/
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV MYSQL_PWD pass123admin

# Fix warning "debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed " during build.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils

# The base Ubuntu images don't come with sudo, so Add sudo
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo

# Install JDK 8
RUN echo "deb http://debian.opennms.org/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && curl -sS http://debian.opennms.org/OPENNMS-GPG-KEY | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && echo "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | debconf-set-selections \
    && apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y

## Install all software available via apt-get
RUN echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $MYSQL_PWD" | debconf-set-selections \
    && echo "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $MYSQL_PWD" | debconf-set-selections \
    && apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
        mysql-server
```

Everything works as expected for building the image and creating the container.

But whenever I tried to remove the Docker-Container created using this image. It is not removing MY-SQL layer within it.

I used ***$ docker rm mycontainer mycontainer*** command to delete the container created using above image.

But when I recreated the container using above image (also uses ***--force-recreate*** option), I was able to see my previous data in MySql Database. This means ***$ docker rm*** can not remove the container completely with underlying layers.

Is there a way to delete completely remove docker-container including it's underlying layers of MySQL or JDK?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about [pruning](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/)?

Comment: Not exactly, ***$ docker system prune*** removes stopped-container, dangling-images and build-cache. I am using ***$ docker rm container-name container-name*** command to remove only docker-container. Actual issue is to remove container completely(including underlying layer e.g MySql) and re-create it fresh.